# CSS navbar slider highlight animation?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, navbar

I'm trying to create a top navigation bar with an underline that slides underneath each link/button on hover. I'm guessing either transitions or keyframes would work but I can't seem to make it work.

Here's my best shot, but I can only make the parent nav or div the trigger and not the actual links themselves, and also I can't get the bar to slide to a position relative to the links (right now it's just translating 500px to the right).

Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
#header {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 width: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav ul li {
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 11px;
}

.slider {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: -50px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.3);
 transition-property: transform;
 transition-duration: 300ms;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav:hover .slider {
   transform: translate(500px);
}

.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

```html
<header id="header">
       <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="list">
              <div class="slider"></div>
         <li class="btn"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
         <li class="btn"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li class="btn"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
         <li class="btn"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
       </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe go for something like this?

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
}).has("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("current");
```

```css
  .nav {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 11px;
  }

ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
  }

  a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 }

 .home.current ~ hr,
   ul li.home:hover ~ hr {
   margin-left: 0%;
 }
   
  .about.current ~ hr,
   li.about:hover ~ hr {
      margin-left: 25%;
   }
  
  .portfolio.current ~ hr,
   li.portfolio:hover ~ hr {
    margin-left: 50%;
   }

  .contact.current ~ hr,
   li.contact:hover ~ hr {
   margin-left: 75%;
   }

hr {
 height: 3px;
 width: 25%;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219, 0.3);
 transition-property: transform;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
   }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li><!--
   --><li class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li><!--
   --><li class="portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li><!--
   --><li class="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <hr />
    </ul>
 </div>
</header>
```

Or do you want the underline to come out of the side of the screen?

EDIT: Added js/jQuery that makes the menu items stick on click.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was thinking to have the underline stick to whichever link is selected, but then I think that makes it harder to make it slide to the right position, since the default position will be different depending on which page you're on.

The only problem with this solution is the margin is changing relative to the screen size (not the actual links), so when I shrink the screen size down, the bar slides to the wrong position.

Comment: @Sean Hey man, just added some js/jQuery to make the underline stick on the currently selected link. I'm a bit confused about your other issue though(changing in screen width). Could you elaborate more?

Comment: That's awesome, man. Exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for your help. Was trying to avoid using JavaScript (as I haven't really learnt it yet), but I guess sometimes you just need it!

Comment: Not a problem. If you're looking to get into JavaScript, I suggest going through freecodecamp.com tutorials. Out of all the learn-it-yourself websites, in my opionion, that one is the best.